# Sorting dictionary by key

Tags: python-3.x, ordereddict

I have a dictionary that have year-month combination as the key and value of it. I used OrderedDict to sort the dictionary and getting result like below. In my expected result, after "2021-1", it should be "2021-2". But "2021-10" is coming in between.

```
{
    "2020-11": 25,
    "2020-12": 861,
    "2021-1": 935,
    "2021-10": 1,
    "2021-2": 4878,
    "2021-3": 6058,
    "2021-4": 3380,
    "2021-5": 4017,
    "2021-6": 1163,
    "2021-7": 620,
    "2021-8": 300,
    "2021-9": 7
}
```

My expected result should be like below. I want the dictionary to be sorted by least date to the last date

```
{
        "2020-11": 25,
        "2020-12": 861,
        "2021-1": 935,
        "2021-2": 4878,
        "2021-3": 6058,
        "2021-4": 3380,
        "2021-5": 4017,
        "2021-6": 1163,
        "2021-7": 620,
        "2021-8": 300,
        "2021-9": 7,
        "2021-10": 1
    }
```

Appreciate if you can help.

Comment: That's because of the lexical string sorting. Fix your date format to always have a two-digit month (e.g. `2021-01`) and the problem goes away.

Comment: strings are sorted Lexicographically. **hint**: use `datetime` module to parse the string and then sort the `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the way sorting is done, use `sorted` with parameter `key`:

```
from typing import OrderedDict
from decimal import Decimal


data = {
    "2020-11": 25,
    "2020-12": 861,
    "2021-1": 935,
    "2021-10": 1,
    "2021-2": 4878,
    "2021-3": 6058,
    "2021-4": 3380,
    "2021-5": 4017,
    "2021-6": 1163,
    "2021-7": 620,
    "2021-8": 300,
    "2021-9": 7
}

def year_plus_month(item):
    key = item[0].replace("-", ".")
    return Decimal(key)

data_ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=year_plus_month))
print(data_ordered)
```

I used `Decimal` instead of `float` to avoid any wonky floating point precision.